# jtabbedpane should not move on scrolling the panel down

Tags: java, swing, scroll, panel, jtabbedpane

I have a long list of data to be presented in on the jtabbedpanel, on scrolling down for the data the tabbed panel name at the top will not be visible .How can i make the tabbed panel tabs visible at the top even on scrolling down?

Can anyone help on how i can fix this , or mention some posts regarding the same ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: something like https://drupal.org/project/floating_block (floating block drupal ) in css , is there any such thing in swing where i can make  tabedpane headers or the tabs visible even on scrolling ?

Comment: Yes, it's called a `JScrollPane`, but you need to get the context right.  As I said in my answer, instead of putting the `JTabbedPane` inside the scroll pane, put the component that represents the tab inside the scroll pane and add the scroll pane to the tabbed pane.  Take a look at [How to use scrollpanes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

From the sounds of it, you are adding the `JTabbedPane` to the `JScrollPane`.

Instead, add each tab's component to a `JScrollPane` and then add this (the scroll pane) as the tab...

ie...

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(reallyLargePane);
tabbedPane.addTab("Another tab", scrollPane);
```